# change div id by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a simple page to change the div id every time I pressed submit. My problem is that this changes from div_top1 -> div_top2, but the second time I press the button, it stops changing :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>   
            function changediv()
            {                                                    
                document.getElementById("div_top1").innerHTML=Date();          
                document.getElementById("div_top1").setAttribute("id", "div_top2");
                document.getElementById("div_top2").innerHTML="teste";            
                document.getElementById("div_top2").setAttribute("id", "div_top1");
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            .top {               
                background-color: navy;    
                color: white;
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;   
                margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;                                 
            }

            .down {             
                background-color: aqua;
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;        
            }         
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div_top1" class="top">This is a paragraph.</div>
        <div class="down"><button type="button" onclick="changediv()">Display Date</button></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I ask WHY do you want to change ID? Why not classname? The ID only changes once because second time your cant find the first ID

Comment: Would you not be safer changing the class of a div?

Comment: In your code the moment you change div_top1 for example to div_top2 then it would stay there. Unless you put an if to toggle it then it would keep on changing.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4aE46/

Comment: well, yes, but when I press the button again, doesn't the function start again?

Comment: second click also working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4aE46/1/

Comment: To answer the question on why change the ID when you can change the classname: For my situation, I am using an 'uninvited button' click event to hide a particular DIV for an invited user. The DIV gets its name from the user's id. So, if I then invite the same user, because I accidentally uninvited them, there will be two DIVS with the same ID tag. Changing the first ID when it is hidden, allows for the second DIV to be created with a unique ID; thus other click events can act on it. Very special use case; but, there are reasons for wanting to change an ID. Though, I agree, not many IMHO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/6s78L/)**</kbd>

Try this:

```
function changediv()
{   

    if (document.getElementById("div_top1")) {
        document.getElementById("div_top1").innerHTML=Date();          
        document.getElementById("div_top1").setAttribute("id", "div_top2");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("div_top2").innerHTML="teste";            
        document.getElementById("div_top2").setAttribute("id", "div_top1");
    }


}
```

Comment: sometimes, the only thing it take is to have someones push :D
Thank you, this works fine, and now I got why my solution didn't.... I was setAttribute twice ...

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was needing. I mention in the comments on the question why I needed to change the ID name. Thank you for posting this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the changing id - it's that you're changing it both ways every time.  You need an if condition.  You should also use .id to change the id instead of setAttribute() - I've had issues with some browsers in the past (many years ago) using setAttribute for id changes.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/x2nPY/

```
function changediv() {
    if (document.getElementById("div_top1")) {
        document.getElementById("div_top1").innerHTML = Date();          
        document.getElementById("div_top1").id = "div_top2";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("div_top2").innerHTML = "teste";            
        document.getElementById("div_top2").id = "div_top1";
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way... is it possible to make a include like .include = "index.php" ? I would like to include different pages in the div...

Comment: You can use AJAX to load content from the server and then .innerHTML to place it in the div.

Answer (score 1):

You could use if for example if you want to toggle it or change every time you submit like:

```
function changediv() {                                           
if (document.getElementById("div_top1"))
 {
    document.getElementById("div_top1").innerHTML=Date();          
    document.getElementById("div_top1").setAttribute("id", "div_top2");

 }
 else
 {
    document.getElementById("div_top2").innerHTML="teste";            
    document.getElementById("div_top2").setAttribute("id", "div_top1");
 }

}
```

See the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdy_dot/65hXL/)